# CSS Image Gallery adjustments

Tags: css, gallery

I need a simple image gallery so I decided to build it entirly on CSS, and tried to find something appropriate in the net.I found something very close to what I want, here are the applied CSS styles:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Gallery</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 500px;
    color: #000000;
    font: normal 80%/120% Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
a
{
    color: #000000;
}

.gallery {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.gallery li {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
    height: 100px;
}
.gallery img {
    background: #fff;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    padding: 4px;
    width: 110;
    height: 90;
}
.gallery span {
    width: 77px;
    height: 27px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -12px;
    left: 50px;
    background: url(images/tape.png) no-repeat;
}
.gallery a:hover img {border: 1px solid #0000ff; width:400; height:300; overflow: auto}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul class="gallery">
    <li><a href="#"><span></span><img src="image/8.jpg" alt="image" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span></span><img src="image/9.jpg" alt="image" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span></span><img src="image/4.jpg" alt="image" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span></span><img src="image/7.jpg" alt="image" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span></span><img src="image/5.jpg" alt="image" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span></span><img src="image/6.jpg" alt="image" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span></span><img src="image/3.jpg" alt="image" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span></span><img src="image/1.jpg" alt="image" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span></span><img src="image/2.jpg" alt="image" /></a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

In fact I don't even know why i need `.gallery span{}` (maybe some tips here) But the main problem is this:
Pic1:

[image]

This is how my gallery looks and I want it to look just like that, but when i a:hover and enlarge the image here's what happen

Pic2:

[image]

and to make it clear one more picture

Pic3:

[image]

What I need, and want to accomplish is all enlarged images to appear like this:

Pic4:

[image]

but obviously in front of the thumbnails.Any help please.

Thanks

Leron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to your body style, remove `position: relative;` from .gallery li, and add `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;` to .gallery a:hover img.

Your final CSS being:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
        width: 500px;
        color: #000000;
        font: normal 80%/120% Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        position: relative;
    }
    a
    {
        color: #000000;
    }

    .gallery {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .gallery li {
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 0;
        float: left;
        width: 120px;
        height: 100px;
    }
    .gallery img {
        background: #fff;
        border: solid 1px #ccc;
        padding: 4px;
        width: 110;
        height: 90;
    }
    .gallery span {
        width: 77px;
        height: 27px;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: -12px;
        left: 50px;
        background: url(images/tape.png) no-repeat;
    }
    .gallery a:hover img {border: 1px solid #0000ff; width:400; height:300; overflow: auto; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;}
    </style>
```

Comment: additionally, for proper layering - you'll need to set the z-index of all items to, say 1, and add z-index:2 to your hover class. That being said, a little javascript would add a lot to your project.

Comment: To Kyle B : Thanks, exactly what I wanted.

Comment: To Bosworth99, thanks man, maybe in future I'll try to make something more coplicated, but for now this do the trick, but if it's not a problem, could you tell me, how the z-index will benefit my gallery as it is?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the z-index property:

```
.gallery a:hover img {
    ....
    z-index: 10;
}
```